# Error with submitting username and password for user registration

Tags: php, html, post

I'm new to PHP but I have some experience with HTML and JavaScript. This is my webpage, it's a simple register screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error{color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $name = $password = $confirmPassword = $email = $phone = "";
        $nameErr = $passwordErr = $confirmPasswordErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = "";

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            //echo "insdie if";
            if(empty($_POST["name"])){
                $nameErr = "Name is required";
            }else {
                $name = $_POST["name"];
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                }
            }
            if($_POST["password"]){
                $nameErr = "password is required";
                if(!$_POST["confirmPassword"]){
                    $confirmPasswordErr = "Confirm password doesn't match password.";
                }
            }else {
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                if($password < 8){
                    $passwordErr = "Password should contain more than 8 characters";
                }else
                {
                    if(empty($_POST["confirmPassword"])){
                        $confirmPasswordErr = "Confirm password and password dont match";
                    }else {
                        $confirmPassword = $_POST["confirmPassword"];
                        if($confirmPassword != $password){
                            $confirmPasswordErr = "Confirm password and password dont match";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if(empty($_POST["email"])){
                $nameErr = "Email is required";
            }else {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            }
            echo "".$name."";

            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }
        }       
        ?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <h1>Register to CabsOnline</h1>
        <p>Please fill th fields below to complete your registration</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"/><span class="error"><?php $nameErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"/><span class="error"><?php $passwordErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword"/><span class="error"><?php $confirmPasswordErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Emal:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"/><span class="error"><?php $emailErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>phone:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone"/><span class="error"><?php $phoneErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>        

        <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        <br/>

        <h4>Already registered?</h4><a href="login.php">Loging here</a>
    </form>
</body>
```

The code doesn't add the validation and I can't find out why. What do I have to do to get the value from the textboxes only when submit is clicked? I've changed it around but I just can't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually echo the strings.

```
<?php $nameErr;?>
```

on its own doesn't do anything, it should be

```
<?php echo $nameErr;?>
```

Comment: that fixed it. thank you! will accept as answer when allowed.

Comment: @NirubanNicholas: i think u have permission to accept it.

Comment: @devpro there is a timeout 15 minutes after asking a question to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

your validation is working fine but the issue is that you are not printing the err msgs... like `<td><input type="text" name="name"/><span class="error"><?php $nameErr;?></span></td>` here you are not printing the value of `$nameErr` you need to `echo` the value of `$nameErr` like this

```
<td><input type="text" name="name"/><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
```

Comment: the problem i have is that that code executes on page load. I need something like `<form onsubmit="myFunction()">`. Do you have any suggestions on what i can use?

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
 if(isset($_POST['name'])){
      if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        //echo "insdie if";
        if(empty($_POST["name"])){
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        }else {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
        }
        if($_POST["password"]){
            $nameErr = "password is required";
            if(!$_POST["confirmPassword"]){
                $confirmPasswordErr = "Confirm password doesn't match password.";
            }
        }else {
            $password = $_POST["password"];
            if($password < 8){
                $passwordErr = "Password should contain more than 8 characters";
            }else
            {
                if(empty($_POST["confirmPassword"])){
                    $confirmPasswordErr = "Confirm password and password dont match";
                }else {
                    $confirmPassword = $_POST["confirmPassword"];
                    if($confirmPassword != $password){
                        $confirmPasswordErr = "Confirm password and password dont match";
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if(empty($_POST["email"])){
            $nameErr = "Email is required";
        }else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
        echo "".$name."";

        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
    } 

    }
```

this will check if the form has been submitted or not and set the err messages only if the form is submitted

Comment: additionally there is no need of  'if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")' now

Answer (score 0):

answer of @iainn is correct.

Additionally you can use client side validations using `Javascript / jQuery` which will prevent page reloading each time.

Use

```
<form method="post" name="formname" onsubmit="return validateform()">
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateform()" />
```

then add

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function() validatefrom(){
   //your javascript validations
} 
</script>
```

in header or footer part of document and write your javascript validations.